# 'For' loop with AJAX query within 'for' loop with AJAX query issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, for-loop

Good day, everyone!
I have two nested 'for' loops with an ajax request and appended items in each of them.
Outer loop appends category name (I have three categories overall), inner loop appends items of the oter loop's current category. 
It appends category names and appropriate category items in needed places. The problem is that all the three category names are of the last category (the third one).
May the reason be that I create functions within a loop?

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost/mysite/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?parent=" + categoryId + "",
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "GET",
  success: function (subheaders) {
    $("#gallery").empty();

    if (subheaders.length > 0) {
      for (i = 0; i < subheaders.length; i++) {
        var subHeaderName = subheaders[i].name;
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost/mysite/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=" + subheaders[i].id + "",
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: "GET",
          success: function (items) {
            $("#gallery").append($("<h3 class=\"subcat\">" + subHeaderName + "</h3>"));
            for (j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
              $("#gallery").append($("<div id=" + items[j].id + " class=\"gallery-item\"><div class=\"item-header\">" + items[j].title.rendered + "</div></div>"));
            }
          },

          error: function () {
            $("#catalogue-img").find("#gallery").append($("Server Error. Please, come back later or call us."));
          }
        });
      }
    }
  },

  error: function () {
    $("#catalogue-img").find("#gallery").append($("Server Error. Please, come back later or call us."));
  }
});
```

Comment: this is because ajax is async. so your script will keep running wheter you already get response or not. you need callback to solve this. or you can change your workflow. CMIIW

Comment: Adding async:false to my ajax request properties totally solved the problem. Thank you a LOT!!!

Comment: nooo.. dont do that. you will make your browser hang. chrome will warn you about this in console. avoid that. use callback better

Comment: I see. Okay. I'll try this out tomorrow.